# What is the meaning of infinite input impedance and saturation in OP amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is the meaning of infinite input impedance and saturation in OP amp ?

Comment: CMOS opamps will appear as ?5pF? capacitors (which will be somewhat voltage dependent and thus nonlinear) in parallel with temperature-dependent leakage currents thru FET gate oxides and thru junctions of the ESD structures. Now regarding saturation?

Comment: pretty much what the individual words mean – can you try to specify what you don't understand by **editing** your question, please? (don't just comment, that will get lost in time)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of infinite input impedance and saturation in OP amp ?

"Infinite input impedance" means no current flows into or out of the input terminals. As analogsystemsrf pointed out in comments, this is not quite true and because of input gate capacitance, some current will flow in if you apply an AC voltage. Also, if you apply a voltage outside the power supply rails, it's likely some current will flow in or out through ESD protection structures.

"Saturation" means the op-amp can't produce an output above its positive supply voltage or below its negative supply voltage. If you set up a circuit that would produce such a voltage for an ideal op-amp, a real op-amp will enter the *saturation* operating regime and produce an output voltage somewhat below the positive supply or above the negative supply. The exact amount below or above depends on the design of the op-amp and the current drawn by the load and feedback network.